# Replacing an item that is dissimilar between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays:

```
var alleditvals= {username: "twooooo", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};
var a= {username: "two", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};
```

Now i want only the difference (i.e "twoooo") to be replaced into the object `a` such that `a` also becomes like `alleditvals`.

Actually in my code, `a` comes from an array called `add_data`, so i use the `map` function:

```
add_data.map((a,i)=>
  i===count_edit ? alleditvals : a
)
```

here `count_edit` is just a number that i update, and then i check if the index of `add_data` matches `count_edit`, then include the value of `alleditvals`, else keep the `add_data` value (which is `a`). But the problem with this method is that it replaces every object inside the `add_data` if the condition holds true, i mean fields like `password` and `address` are also replaced. so please suggest a method where i can selectively replace only thw item where chang has occured.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the properties that need to be replaced, or the properties that should be excluded?

Comment: First, those are not arrays. Second, if you need `a` to equal `alleditvals`, why not assign it? `a = alleditvals`?

Comment: @Kraylog He said he doesn't want to replace the password and address properties.

Comment: @Barmar http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I don't understand **i can selectively replace only thw item where chang has occured.** If you replace properties where no change has occurred, what's the difference? It's still the same.

Comment: `@Kraylog`, that's not a primitive value. The Object will be affected upon assignment of its properties. You could do `a.username = alleditvals.username`.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You want a to equal alleditvals, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you don’t want a to equal alleditvals, because as Kraylog said, in that case you could have just assigned it (except the fact that then all properties that were in a, but not in alleditvals, would be lost)

What you may wanna do is to loop through the properties of your given object and copy only the fields, that match your criteria, eg:

```
for (x in alleditvals) {
    if (x === “username”) {
        a[x] = alleditvals[x];
    }
    // more if x === ... stuff
}
```

To really do what you asked for (overwriting the differences and persisting the properties of a that do not occur in alleditvals) try something like:

```
for (x in alleditvals) {
    if (
        a.hasOwnProperty(x) // to only replace if a contains a key of alleditvals
        && a[x] !== alleditvals[x]
        ) {
        a[x] = alleditvals[x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using modern javascript you can achieve this simply with [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
a = { ...alleditvals, ...a }
```

Now `a` will have all the original properties of `a` plus any from `alleditvals` that are not already defined by `a`.

If, instead, you wanted both the new values from `alleditvals` *and* to replace anything in `a` with the same prop value from `alleditvals` -- i.e. merging over `a` -- then just reverse the order:

```
a = { ...a, ...alleditvals }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign`.

```
var alleditvals= {username: "twooooo", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};
var a= {username: "two", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};

a = Object.assign(a, alleditvals);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, it can be a good approach for what you are looking for:

```
var alleditvals= {username: "twooooo", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};


var a= {username: "two", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};
var b= {username: "three", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};
var c= {username: "four", password: "two_p", address: "two_add"};

let add_data=[a,b,c];

for (let x in add_data) {
   if(add_data[x].username!==alleditvals.username){
     add_data[x].username=alleditvals.username
   }
   /* other fields is same:
   if(add_data[x].password!==alleditvals.password){
     add_data[x].password=alleditvals.password
   }
   */
}


console.log(add_data)
```

You can change and run this code from [here](https://repl.it/repls/GrossLostSet).